# printing element separting by white space instead of tab

Tags: perl

The following loop can print out these elements separating by tab.

```
for my $j (1 .. 10)
{
     printf filehandler "\t%f", $j;
 }
```

I would like to know how to print out these elements separating by “White Space” in stead of “Tab”. I tried to change `\t` into `\s`, it did not work.

Comment: "White space"...? Whitespace is a term for a character class consisting of either tabs, space, newline, etc. It is not a specific character.

Comment: In other words, in case it was not clear: Your question cannot be answered in its current state. You need to define what character you are referring to.

Comment: @TLP, he surely means "spaces"

Comment: It's a "file handle", not a "file handler". It doesn't handle anything, so "handler" makes no sense. It allows one to keep a hold on a resources, thus "handle".

Comment: @ikegami I thought that anyone asking how to print a space was too improbable.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
for my $j (1 .. 10)
{
  printf filehandler " %f", $j;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

more idiomatically perl:

```
print filehandler join " ", (1 .. 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
printf $fh "%10f", $j;
```

Adjust the size to your liking.